# How do I update navigationState from within my UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate class?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Goal: when user taps notification, open the app to a specified screen

My first attempt was to pass a piece of state into the delegate and update it from within the `didReceive`. Error, of course, is `Cannot use instance member 'navigationPath' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    private let delegate = UNCDelegate(navigationPath: navigationPath) // Error: Cannot use instance member 'navigationPath' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
    
    init() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = delegate
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
        }
    }
}

class UNCDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        // user opened notif. update navigationPath so the app opens at specified screen
    }
}
```

Comment: You can initialize delegate in your `init`. Also, be sure to make `navigationPath` a `Binding` inside `UNCDelegate`.

Comment: `UNCDelegate` isn't a `View`, so can't contain a `Binding`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a (non-class) delegate to your `UNCDelegate` and make that the  `App` itself. In the example below I've renamed `UNCDelegate` to `NotificationHandler` for to avoid delegate confusion!

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @State private var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
    private let notificationHandler = NotificationHandler()
    
    init() {
        notificationHandler?.delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = notificationHandler
    }
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
        }
    }
}

extension MyApp: NotificationHandlerDelegate {
    func notificationHandler(_ notificationHandler: NotificationHandler, didReceiveResponse: UNNotificationResponse) {
        navigationPath.append("something")
    }
}

protocol NotificationHandlerDelegate {
    func notificationHandler(_ notificationHandler: NotificationHandler, didReceiveResponse: UNNotificationResponse)
}

class NotificationHandler: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var delegate: NotificationHandlerDelegate?
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        delegate?.notificationHandler(self, didReceiveResponse: response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this, but I'm having an issue where the `navigationPath` doesn't update after appending. I print before and after and the value is still `[]`. Also, I don't understand what the appended value should be. Is it supposed to match `navigationTitle` of the view I want to nav to?

Comment: Are you creating a new `NavigationPath()` elsewhere in your app? The value you append can be anything, you just need to check what is passed into .`navigationDestination` and return the appropriate View.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack

Comment: I've been looking at the docs but something isn't clicking for me. My nav link looks like this: `NavigationLink (destination: DetailView(thing: thing)) { ZStack {...} }`. So there is no `navigationDestination`